# Signed executable not showing timestamp and different encryption

Tags: delphi, code-signing

I signed my 32-bits Delphi 10.3.3 executable with a code signing certificate.
The right-click option *Properties/Digital signatures* shows the `sha1` digest algorithm and no timestamp:

[image]

Why does this say `sha1` digest algorithm and no timestamp?
Is that important? Should/can I change that?

Here's the sequence of events:

- Bought the certificate from Sectigo, valid for three years
- When everything was verified I got an email telling where I could download it, **in IE**. This installed the cert in my Win10 certificate store.
  Here is the `Certmgr.msc` screenshot for the Personal/Certicates folder:
  [image]
- Right clicked on the certificate, chose Export, *Yes, export the private key*, then default options:
  [image]
- Supplied a pasword, and chose AES256-SHA256 Encryption:
  [image]
  (I did this twice to make sure I had not accidentally picked TripleDES-SHA1)
- Stored it on disk
- Installed the Windows SDK so that *signtool* is available
- Signed the executable with
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x86\signtool.exe" sign /f "d:\Online Kleuranalyse\Certs\imagecompanion.pfx" /p password "d:\Online Kleuranalyse\oca.exe
  This says: *Successfully signed: d:\Online Kleuranalyse\OCA.exe*

Comment: You need to pass /t or /tr switch with timestamp server if you want to include timestamp when you are signing.

Comment: sha1 is basically useless.